# Trying to convert a 7 digit julian date into MMDDYY format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, julian-date

I'm trying to convert a 7 digit julian/mainframe date into a calendar date of format mmddyy in SQL Server.
An example of this being julian date **2005020**, where the first 4 digits are the year, 2005, and the last three are the day number in a calendar, so 020 = january 20. So I'd need to get this date as 012005(MMDDYY) in SQL Server.

I've been using the following query but keep getting an error after it loads a few records:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,CAST(RIGHT([julianDateColumn],3) as int)-,LEFT([julianDateColumn],4))
```

The error I've been getting:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Originally I was doing this in an Access DB using the "DATESERIAL" function but from what I've seen the closest thing to that in SQL Server was "DATEFROMPARTS", I tried using the following formula but it also didn't work:

```
DATEFROMPARTS([julianDateColumn]/1000,1,[julianDateColumn] % 1000)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Skip YYMMDD, use YYYY-MM-DD instead! (I see 050120 as May 1:st 2020, or was it January 5th?.)

Comment: What about `070809` @jarlh? Is that 07 August 2009, 08 July 2009, 09 August 2007, or perhaps even 08 September 2007. ;)

Comment: @Larnu, my grandmother was born in 1907. Looks like a date that year.

Comment: Of course, how foolish of me to not list 1907 August 09. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would seem to be to take the left as the year, and the add the days (-1) to make a date. Also, rather than using a format of `MMDDYY` I'm going to go straight a `date` datatype. If you want it in a specific format, that's for your presentation layer.

```sql
SELECT JulianDate,
       CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,RIGHT(JulianDate,3)-1,CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(JulianDate,4)))) AS ActualDate --4 int strings are iterpreted as the year, so I'm going to take advantage of that
FROM (VALUES('2005020'))V(JulianDate);
```

---

Based on the comments on the answer, it appears that the OP has some dates that don't conform to the format that stated (`yyyyddd`). Therefore what we could use here is a calendar table, here, and then `LEFT JOIN` to it and see what bad rows you get (and `INNER JOIN` to get the dates).

You can create the table with something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.CalendarTable (CalendarDate date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                                CalenderYear AS DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate) PERSISTED,
                                CalenderMonth AS DATEPART(MONTH, CalendarDate) PERSISTED,
                                CalenderDay AS DATEPART(DAY, CalendarDate) PERSISTED,
                                CalenderMonthName AS DATENAME(MONTH, CalendarDate),
                                JulianDate AS DATEPART(YEAR,CalendarDate) * 1000 + DATEDIFF(DAY,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate),1,1),CalendarDate) + 1 PERSISTED); --Some example columns



WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6),
Dates AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY, T.I, '19000101')) AS CalendarDate
    FROM Tally T)
INSERT INTO dbo.CalendarTable(CalendarDate)
SELECT CalendarDate
FROM Dates
WHERE CalendarDate < '21000101';
GO
```

Then we can do something like this to get the bad rows:

```sql
SELECT YT.JulianDate
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN dbo.CalendarTable CT ON YT.JulianDate = CT.JulianDate
WHERE CT.JulianDate IS NULL;
```

Comment: That worked! Unfortunately it's still throwing the same error of "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." after it loads some records.

Comment: Sounds like you have some invalid value then, @Roger. This is why storing data in anything other than an actual date datatype is a poor idea. WE need more sample data here, specifically the values that aren't converting.

Comment: Seems like a calendar table might be a better solution, so you can find the bad dates too.

Comment: Added a calendar table solution you can use to find your bad data, @Roger .

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much! I've narrowed it down to a specific library which contains this bad data, I'll be testing it later tonight to see what I can find, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use `datefromparts()` and `dateadd()`:

```
select dateadd(day,
               right(juliandate, 3) - 1),
               datefromparts(left(juliandate, 4), 1, 1)
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select Format(cast(concat(substring('2005020', 1, 4), '-', Month(cast(substring('2005020', 5, len('2005020')) as int)) ,'-', day(dateadd(day,-1,cast(substring('2005020', 5, len('2005020')) as int ) )  )) as date), 'MMddyy')
```